# Is it possible to give access to a bucket in Google Storage with a Google User ID instead of Email?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to give access to a bucket in Google Storage with a Google User ID instead of Email?

I am working on an application that uploads file from using the Javascript APIs for Google Cloud Storage. I manage the ACLs for the bucket in my own AppEngine backend.

I'd like to be able to give access to specific people who I don't have access to their emails but got their Google IDs through Google+ APIs search. Is it possible to do that?

If not, what else can I use to give access to a user that haven't authorized my application (yet)?

In ACL Insert [API documentation there's a reference to `user-userId`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls/insert), but I am not sure if that refers to the special user ID for the Cloud Storage or a general Google User ID? If it is the former can an application ask what is the user ID of a user without knowing their email?

Comment: You should be able to get their emails if you have the Google+ userID.  https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

Comment: I don't think this is true. Google+ ID is available via the public search API getting the user email they'd have to authorize access to. Which is not what I am asking. I'd like to give them access without needing to ask for their authorization.

Comment: OK, I thought they already authorized you. Without authorization or they giving you their email, there's no way to add them to ACL. An alternative would be to add the files in public mode (open to everybody) and scramble the name in a way that it would not be easy to find it (like URL shorteners do but in a longer string).

Comment: Thanks @Mario, I think it isn't possible either, I hoped the user-userId was the general Google ID which you can get from public search but I think that ID is specific to GCS. In anyway, I've implemented this functionality to give the users access when they first authorize my app (and my app is able to get their email).